# Can't find this field under any object in Salesforce

Tags: object, object-manager

Im building a report under "Contacts with Activities" and there is a field called "Assigned". I tried looking in every single object, in object manager, and the closest thing I could find was under the events object called "Assigned To". But curious why this field is not under Activity? Im trying to use this to mirror a custom field on the Contact object to show that same value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Activities have a few standard objects, [OpenActivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm) and [ActivityHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm). These two objects combine open and closed tasks and events into their own separate entities. For each, there is a common field OwnerId that is the Task Owner or Event Owner. You won't find them in setup directly, though, but should be in the documentation.